# How to join a table and filter some rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm sorry for the bad English.

So I have a select sql returns result like this:

```
Aid   type  name
1     1     a   
2     1     b
3     2     c
4     2     d
5     3     e
6     3     f
7     3     g
```

And another select returns result like this:

```
Bid  Aid type   content key
3    5   3      aaa     1
9    7   3      bbb     1
10   10  2      ccc     2
```

And I want to get this:

```
Aid Bid  type name content  
5   3    3    e    aaa
6   NULL 3    f    NULL
7   9    3    g    bbb
```

How can I do that?

```
select Aid, type, name from tableA
(HOW to JOIN???) ( 
   select Bid, type, content from tableB where key = 1
) on tableA.Aid = tableB.Aid
```

Comment: Look at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: can you give more explanation here? you just post the result of the query you've tried, please post the tables with info and the result you want

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are some good tutorials on [w3schools on joining](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp), but assuming you want to join `t1` with `t2` using `Aid` as key:

```
SELECT t1.Aid, t2.Bid, t1.type, t1.name, t2.content
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.Aid = t2.Aid
WHERE (t2.key = 1) OR (t2.key IS NULL)
```

Note that you need to use `LEFT JOIN`, because there isn't matching `Aid` record in `t2` for every record in `t1` and you want to display `NULL` than.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.Aid, 
       b.bid,
       a.type,
       a.name,
       b.content
FROM tableA AS a LEFT JOIN
     tableB AS b ON a.Aid = b.Aid
WHERE b.key = 1
```

Comment: While this answer may solve the problem, you should elaborate on it a bit and explain what your code does.